# Can't get JSON via RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

There is some API through which you can get json, if I execute this url in a browser or postman, then everything works fine. If I try to get it through restTeamplate, then I get all kinds of "crackers", tried to experiment with the encoding, but nothing happened (commented out sections are my attempts), sometimes other crackers come, here is an example of my code:

```
public String getInfo() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    /*restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));*/

    /*try {
        return new String(restTemplate.getForObject(API, String.class).getBytes(), "UTF-16");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    //return restTemplate.getForEntity(API, String.class);

    return restTemplate.getForObject(API, String.class);
}
```

If you use the getForEntity method, then the postman or browser does not receive a response at all, I see in the postman: enter the image description here [image]

I suspect that I am missing some headers in the request. Who faced a similar problem tell me how it was solved or where is something similar described?

This api has no description, but in the browser this request works fine, tried to use the headers sent by the browser

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> getInfo() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
        httpHeaders.set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.3.314 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36");
        httpHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        HttpEntity<HttpHeaders> entity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
        return restTemplate.exchange(API, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    }
```

Also in the answer there are such headers

[X-Node:"BKLA36-LA", Cache-Control:"no-cache", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*", Access-Control-Allow-Methods:"POST, GET, OPTIONS", Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"Content-Type", Connection:"keep-alive", Content-Encoding:"gzip", Content-Length:"146305"]

Perhaps the problem is Content-Encoding:"gzip"

Comment: Do you have any description of the api you use. Did you check if you have to set the Mediatype in the header field?

Comment: @medTech added to the question

Comment: Did you try to this request with postman? What's the status code you get?

Comment: @medTech i get 200OK

Comment: @medTech added headers to the question, mb compression problem gzip